# Do Layer Normalization in Pytorch without learnable parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

We can add layer normalization in Pytorch by doing: `torch.nn.LayerNorm(shape)`. However, this is layer normalization with learnable parameters. I.e, it's the following equation:

[image]

Does Pytorch have builtin layer normalization without learnable parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`nn.LayerNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html), setting the `elementwise` flag to `False`. This way the layer won't have learnt parameters. See [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/normalization.py#L175-L180) for additional reference.